# CakePHP 3.0 failed to connect to Database

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I am using xampp server with port '8080' for localhost, whereas mysql has the default port. I have installed 'cakePHP 3.0' in a folder name 'cake' inside 'htdocs' folder. i have created database using phpmyadmin and made the following changes in app.php file.

```html
'Datasources' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
            'persistent' => false,
            'host' => 'localhost',
            //'port' => '8080',
            'username' => 'cakephp',
            'password' => 'rJzUvaFaXH7MPpaz',
            'database' => 'cake_bookmarks',
            'encoding' => 'utf8',
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
            'cacheMetadata' => true,
            'quoteIdentifiers' => false,

            //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
        ],
```

I have tried with uncomment the port, in this case server is not responding at all. Is there anything i'm missing to connect to database?

Comment: The port in the Datasources array is the database port, has nothing to do with your Web Server port (8080).  The default port for MySQL is 3306 - if you haven't changed it there is no need to set the port in Datasources.  Try running the php web server:  In a terminal window at your app's root, run 'bin\cake server'.  It will start a server on your localhost, listening on port 8765.  In your browser, type 'http://localhost:8765' and see if your app comes up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to swap `'host' => 'localhost',` by `'host' => '127.0.0.1',` and see if it helps.

You can also connect to MySQL using Unix Socket by specifying the option `'unix_socket' => '/path/to/mysql.sock',`.

On XAMPP running in OS X, socket is located at `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock`